# Formal proof of a very simple fact.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Let $L$ be a first-order language with the predicate symbol $R$, and let $x,y$ be variables in $L$.

I want to show that

$\forall x \forall y R(x,y) \vdash R(y,x)$

Where $\vdash$ means formally prove.

I am using Enderton's A Mathematical Introduction to Logic, so I am using his deductive system. I am allowed to use any theorem to show that there is a formal derivation, except for the completeness theorem.

The best I can do is $\forall x \forall y R(x,y)  \vdash R(z,y)$

where $z$ is a variable distinct from $x$ and $y$. I have been trying for hours, please help. Note that I am not actually looking for a formal proof, I just need to show that one exists.

Comment: Isn't this called the rule of detachment, an "axiomatic" level transformation rule?

Comment: I have never heard of that rule. Can you please provide a link?

Comment: Pls, try here. Will see waht happens: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_ponens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ref to :

- Herbert Enderton, [A Mathematical Introduction to Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=dVncCl_EtUkC&pg=PA112) (2nd ed - 2001), page 112.

The first step is :

> $∀x∀yR(x,y) ⊢ ∀yR(z,y)$, using Axiom.2 with $z$ as $t$ (and *Modus Ponens* rule, of course).

The second step is :

> $∀yR(z,y) ⊢ R(z,x)$, using again Axiom.2 with $x$ as $t$.

Then we use **Generalization Theorem** [page 117] to get :

> $R(z,x) ⊢ ∀zR(z,x)$

and finally we apply again Axiom.2 to have :

> > $∀zR(z,x) ⊢ R(y,x)$.

---

Axiom.2 is :

> $\forall x \alpha \to \alpha^x_t$, where $t$ is a *term* is substitutable for $x$ in $\alpha$.

Comment: What is (A4)? My axioms are labelled 1,2,3,4,... in my book.

Comment: I don't understand the last step. (A4) allows us to take away the for all x and replace the x in the formula with a term, but here x isn't replaced with a term, z is.

Comment: I understand that now. But I have another question about the generalization theorem, doesn't the theorem requires z to not occur free in R(z,x) ?

Comment: @NoppaweeApichonpongpan - the **Gen Th** says : if $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$, then $\Gamma \vdash \forall x \varphi$, **provided that** $x$ is not free in $\Gamma$. In the above proof the set of assumptions $\Gamma$ has only one formula : $\forall x \forall y R(x,y)$ with **no** free vars. Thus, nothing prevents the correct use of **Gen Th**.

Comment: I COMPLETELY understand now. Thank you so much for your patience!